# How can I select multiple date ranges in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to query sales data for 14 different months over a 5 year period. Is it possible to query the individual months in a single query? Below is the query to run a single date; how do i transform to run multiple dates?

```
Select *

From Table

Where
Table.Date Between  '2009-02-02' and '2009-03-01'
```

Comment: Your would add `or` and the additional conditions that you want matched.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with the `or`. I tried that previously but I am guessing I had an error in the code.  Thank You Gordon

Answer (score 0):

This query should work.

```
    Select *
    From Table
    Where
    (Table.Date Between  '2009-02-02' and '2009-03-01')
    or 
    (Table.Date Between  '2009-03-02' and '2009-04-01')
    -- and so on
```

In addition you use extract function to get year, month, day from date this way:

`SELECT EXTRACT (DAY FROM '1996-12-12');`